# How do I keep reading from a keyboard in C while outputting results?

Tags: c

I want to read a string and 4 integers then display what I read then read again a string and 4 integers. I want to keep doing this until i get to the end of file ( hitting ctrl + D). For example :

tennis 4 2 3 2 (hit enter)

(the output)

helloworld 2 8 7 4 (hit enter)

(the output)

Here is what I tried to do :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char name[30];
  int won = 0;
  int lost = 0;
  int tie = 0;
  int streak = 0;
  int ch;

while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    scanf("%s %d %d %d %d",name,&won,&lost,&tie,&streak);
    printf("%s%d%d%d%d",name,won,lost,tie,streak);
}   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh What is that ?

Comment: Please ignore, mix of tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(scanf("%29s%d%d%d%d",name,&won,&lost,&tie,&streak) == 5)
    printf("%s%d%d%d%d",name,won,lost,tie,streak);
```

From `man -s3 scanf`:

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned

Answer (score 0):

Simple, read the documentation of [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and write this

```
while (scanf("%s%d%d%d%d", name, &won, &lost, &tie, &streak) == 5)
    printf("%s: %d %d %d %d\n", name, won, lost, tie, streak);
```

In your code, you are reading all the characters from `stdin` and then calling `scanf()`, so after you press enter the code will call `scanf()` passing all the characters after the first to it.

Also, to prevent overflow you can pass a maximum number of characters as a length modifier to the `"%s"` specifier, which you can also read in the manual at the link above. And finally you should take into account that the `"%s"` specifier will not work if the string have spaces in it.

Comment: 5 not 4, also %s is evil

Comment: Yes I know, i got confused with *4 integers*.